# check and return invalid data

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I need to check the following data and report the number of rows those do not match a given criterion.

```
set 582:1960:4c31ed7dea 2012-03-10~23:55:00\r\n
set 565:388:13c10fd316 2012-03-10~23:55:00\r\n
set 519:348:361189d4b9 extra_text 2012-03-10~23:55:00\r\n
set 498:5634:6047172ecc 2012-03-10~23:55:00\r\n
set 565:0:bf7a80ee4f 2012-03-10~23:55:00
```

1) All lines should start with the word "set" and end with "\r\n"

2) All lines should have exact 3 number of fields delimited by space.

In the example data, it should return the invalid row count: 2 and preferably the entire line.
The third line has an extra word and fifth line does not end correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is good for this. A fairly full-featured script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {ends = fields = total = 0 }

NF != 3 || !/\r$/ {
    total++
    if(NF != 3) fields++
    if(!/\r$/) ends++
    print
}

END {
    printf "Wrong number of fields: " fields
    printf "Did not end in a CR: " ends
    printf "Total: " total
}
```

Short one-liner, only prints offending lines:

```
awk 'NF != 3 || !/\r$/' file
```

Prints and counts total:

```
awk 'NF!=3||!/\r$/{total++} END{print "Total: " total}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the invalid rows:

```
grep -v '^set [^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]*\\r\\n$' FILENAME
```

To print the number of invalid rows:

```
grep -cv '^set [^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]*\\r\\n$' FILENAME
```